# Prometheus alerts first counter value

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

I'm trying to create an alert for errors. There is a metric which counts errors occurred in an application. But when I try to catch its increase it always returns 0.

```
increase(app_error[1h])
```

Even if I do it with an offset `offset 5h`, to the point when it was encountered first, it just disappears. Is there a way to find that first error encounter and its first value increasing(from 0 to 1)? I need to fire the alert only on the first count of that metric.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it resolved by

```
app_error unless app_error offset 1h
```

return left side of the expression `unless` it doesn't have matches in the right side of the expression.

Comment: Ah nice, I will have to remember this query

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: No.

Long answer: No, but you may get around this limitation by initializing your metrics with a value of 0 the moment you declare the respective metric in your code. Maybe there are other solutions as well I cannot think of right now.

The reason is that your metric `app_error` only starts to "exist" in Prometheus once it gets incremented the first time. Therefore `increase` will give you an increase of 0 (from nothing to 1 is... 0).

Comment: Thanks, but got it resolved by `app_error unless app_error offset 1h`.

Answer (score 2):

This is the ultimate solution I've come up with so far:

```
sum(increase(app_error[1h]) or vector(0)) 
   + sum((app_error unless app_error offset 1h) or vector(0))
```

The first part `sum(increase(app_error[1h]) or vector(0))`:

- if we have value 7 one hour ago and value 9 now then it will return 2
- it will sum the increases for all instances publishing this metric
- if one hour ago there were no values then `vector(0)` will be returned

The second part `sum((app_error unless app_error offset 1h) or vector(0))`:

- if we have value 1 now and we had no value 1 hour ago - it will return 1
- it will sum the first counter values for all instances publishing this metric
- if we had a value 1 hour ago then `vector(0)` will be returned

Conclusion: when you sum these 2 up you should detect either an increase or first counter increment.

Comment: Works great for one time series! However if we wanted to sum by a certain label (i.e. to see a resulting time series for each label value of a label), how could we change the query? Because simply adding `sum by () ()` on each sum wouldn't work, since the `X or vector(0)` doesn't work if X has multiple time series.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to sum by certain label(s) there is the best I could find:

```
sum by (label1, label2) (max_over_time(app_error[2m]) or vector(0)) 
- sum by (label1, label2) (max_over_time(app_error[1m] offset 1m) or vector(0))
```

I've found it in this discussion applied my own labels and fiddled with ranges to make it work for my case:
https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/issues/1673#issuecomment-508485652